# Single click triggered on a double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to cancel click/mouseup events when double-click event detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067464/need-to-cancel-click-mouseup-events-when-double-click-event-detected)

I am trying to get a HTML object to behave differently when a `single` or `double` click event happens.

Currently with my working example http://jsfiddle.net/9vvEG/ the single click is triggered on the double click, I wish for my code to listen exclusively for the event pre-configured.  ***i.e. if double clicked ignore single click and vice versa.***

No success as of yet, but if you click my example link above you can see the error in progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to note the time between two clicks using setTimeout. Look a solution here:

- [Need to cancel click/mouseup events when double-click event detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067464/need-to-cancel-click-mouseup-events-when-double-click-event-detected/1067484#1067484)

This may also help you:

- [Javascript with jQuery: Click and double click on same element, different effect, one disables the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471291/javascript-with-jquery-click-and-double-click-on-same-element-different-effect)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067464/need-to-cancel-click-mouseup-events-when-double-click-event-detected/1067484#1067484

That was a great answer.

Answer (score 9):

From the jQuery docs on [`dblclick`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/):

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the click and dblclick
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two click events before
>   the dblclick and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum
>   time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by
>   operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

It seems that there is going to be no reliable way to determine whether the user intended a double click or two single clicks, but if you want to try, you could perhaps use `setTimeout` in a `click` event handler to see if another click occurs within a certain period of time.

Comment: +1 Also it's not a good user experience if clicking and double-clicking both do something. After all, when clicking once you expect something to happen immediately, which is not possible if it has to wait to check for a double-click too.

Comment: Hello and thanks James, your answer explains the mechanics and the logic behind what i applied in the end. +1