# Double click not working in backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to capture double click event in Backbone view

```
var HomePage = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function(){
        this.render();
     },
     render: function(){
        var template = _.template($('#app1').html());
        this.$el.html(template);
     },
     events: {
        'click #btn1': function(){
            alert('Single Click');
        },
        'dblclick #btn1': function(){
           alert('Double click');
        }
     } 
});

var view1 = new HomePage({
    el: '#container'
});
```

Double click does not work in backbone. How do we capture it?

Similar to

```
$('#btn1').on('dblclick', function(){
    alert('Double click');
});
```

Comment: Executive summary: jQuery strongly recommends that you don't even try this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your `alert` is firing after a single click and halting execution.  Changing your `alert`s to `console.log`s will show that both events are firing as expected:

```
events: {
    'click #btn1': function() {
        console.log('single click');
    },
    'dblclick #btn1': function() {
       console.log('double click');
    }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvLgybom/

You will then likely run into the issue of both single and double clicks firing. This is discussed further here: [Backbone.js - Both click and double click event getting fired on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286323/backbone-js-both-click-and-double-click-event-getting-fired-on-an-element)