# Double click ambiguity in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click, double-click

I am trying to set some text in window for `single and double click in jquery`.

But I am facing the `ambiguity` for `double click`.

When trying to do `double click` , first `single click` function works and then `double click` works.

Similar question is here [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471291/javascript-with-jquery-click-and-double-click-on-same-element-different-effect) and it was very old. Also it has some problem.

Any new answer using the latest jquery version.

**Check the live demo here of my problem** [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4788T/113/)

This my code ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="press" href="http://jquery.com">Click here</a>
<div id="log"></div>

<script>

$("#press").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#log").text("I am single click !");
return false;
});

$("#press").dblclick(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#log').text("I am double  click !");
      return false;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope our stack users will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the **closest solution** by ,

```
<a id="press" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="singleClick(event)"
    ondblclick="doubleClick(event)">Click here</a>

<div id="log"></div>
```

My **JavaScript** will be ,

```
var timer;
var status = 1;

function singleClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    status = 1;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        if (status == 1) {
            alert("I am single click !");
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML ='I  am single click !';
        }
    }, 500);

}

function doubleClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    status = 0;
    alert("I am double click !");
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = 'I  am a double  click!';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way around the problem is to use a timeout for the click event to give the user time to doubleclick.
If the user clicks twice within a certain timeframe, it's a doubleclick, if the user only clicks once, it's a normal click:

```
$('#press').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( $(this).data('dblclicked') ) {
        $('#log').text('No google today!');
        clearTimeout( $(this).data('clicked') );
        $(this).data('dblclicked', false);
    }else{
        var self = this;
        $(this).data('dblclicked', true).data('clicked', setTimeout(function() {
            $('#log').text('google !');
            $(self).data('dblclicked', false);
        },300));
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4788T/115/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply , Not working properly and please check it.

Comment: @KitePlayer - yeah, forgot the different scope in the timeout, should work now.

Comment: Old thread - just wanted to add my thanks to adeneo. The concept worked great in IE10 - a few glitches, but I worked around them. Thanks very much!