# how to call seperate function on 'click' and 'double click' on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

How to apply both events **click** and **double click** on a single selected table row 'tr', where tr is dynamically bound with foreach knockout binding.

On single click it should call one function, on double click it should call another function.

Can any one help?

Comment: post some code. or put up a fiddle. it'd be easier that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Comment: see this too:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471291/javascript-with-jquery-click-and-double-click-on-same-element-different-effect

Comment: Use dblclick in jquery. Refer http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Thanks you.... it works fine but i need something more like knockout if possible.... i can use this instead... anyways ... it was a great help... thanks again

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea should be to put a timer after the first click and if another click was not detected, call the `singleclick()` function.