# VueJS how to double doubleclick

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table with columns of different widths. I use sticky headers for which I have to calculate the column widths.

Now I wrote a function to increase the column width by double clicking the header. This works for the first double click. But if I click on it 4 or 6 times nothing happens after the first double click. 
How can I reset the event so that after 2 more clicks the event is triggered again?

When I move the mouse I can do several double clicks one after the other. But that is not the goal.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<th 
  v-for="c in data.columns" 
  v-if="visiblecolumns.includes(c)" 
  v-on:dblclick="COLUMN_DEFINITION[c]+=50" 
  :style="{ 'min-width': COLUMN_DEFINITION[c] + 'px', 'max-width': COLUMN_DEFINITION[c] + 'px' }">
    {{ c }}
</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<th 
  v-for="c in data.columns" 
  v-if="visiblecolumns.includes(c)" 
  @click="changeColumnDefinition" 
  :style="{ 'min-width': COLUMN_DEFINITION[c] + 'px', 'max-width': COLUMN_DEFINITION[c] + 'px' }">
    {{ c }}
</th>
```

From: [vue.js: how to handle click and dblclick events on same element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303982/vue-js-how-to-handle-click-and-dblclick-events-on-same-element), and as suggested by @JBDouble05

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        counter: 0,  // count the clicks
        timer: null  // Needs to be specified here so it can be accessed on both clicks
    },    
    methods: {
        changeColumnDefinition: function(event){
            var self = this
            this.counter++ 
            if(this.counter == 1) {
                this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    // DO NOTHING BUT RESET IN CASE THERES JUST ONE CLICK                    
                    self.counter = 0
                }, 500);  // increase delay as you like
            }else{
                clearTimeout(this.timer);  
                // COLUMN_DEFINITION[c]+=50
                self.counter = 0;
            }         
        }      
    }
});
```

---

**NOTE** This goes beyond the question, but:

I would personally wrap this up in a component, since you probably will have more than one header. If you need to call an outside function just use:

```
this.$emit('someEvent', someValue);
```

To emit an event and then access it in your component as

```
<my-awesome-component @someEvent="someFunction"></my-awesome-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. With a timeout function I had already solved it. I was more interested in resetting the double-click event. But it seems like it's not possible.

Comment: yeah, i tried a little that approach, but i could not reset it either, i had to move the mouse a little, not to get completely out of the element, but at least move it a few pixels away

Comment: Same case with me. Also in different browsers. Thought there might be a way around moving the mouse.

Comment: maybe flashing the element ? hahaha

Comment: What does flashing an element mean?

Comment: exactly what it sounds like...  somehow hide it with v-if and then show it again... to refresh the dom... maybe that refreshes the double click, though i did more testing and you don't have to move a bit, you just cannot do a constant double click...  but if you wait something like a second, it double clicks...

Comment: I'm gonna play around there a little bit. If I found a good opportunity, I'll write it in here

Comment: i tried this and didn't worked :( as i expected... it may be the browser blocking that specific coordinate to generate the double click, cause this happens on jquery too

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is make a modulo variable, and attach an incrementational statement to your `v-on:dblclick` attribute, that adds one to (increments) the value of a variable, and then, add an event listener in your JavaScript file, and when this happens, perform a modulus operation upon that variable: if it's divisible by two (`counter % 2 == 0`), then the user has double-clicked twice. If it's not divisible by two (`counter % 2 != 0`) then they've clicked on it an odd number of times, and you can re-engage the event that occurred when they first double-clicked on it. That was a mouthful, but hopefully you got it, and just ask if you need simplification or further explanation.

Comment: i think this could recognize single clicks as double clicks, if you do a click, then wait a lot and do other click..

Comment: Go ahead and try, I don't know Vue but this seemed like a good idea to me.