# How to bind click and double click events on the same element in CKeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, ckeditor, double-click

I am having an issue with CKeditor click event and double-click events.
Currently, I am binding click event and double click event to the CKEditor dom.

```
    editor.on('doubleclick', function (evt) {
        console.log("doubleclicked");
        //Some ajax calls
    }, null, null, 999 );
    editor.on('click', function (evt) {
        console.log("clicked");
        //Some ajax calls
    }, null, null);
```

An issue with above code is, it fires click event first as well when I double-click the element. Both codes execute when I double click on the element.

Any solution for CKEditor for above case?

My question is related to CKeditor plugin. So I have to bind proper (built-in) events for click and double click.

Comment: [check the link for help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471291/javascript-with-jquery-click-and-double-click-on-same-element-different-effect/10624337)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery bind double click and single click separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330431/jquery-bind-double-click-and-single-click-separately)

Comment: I already have tried above solution. Though it works fine, management won't approve such code as it seems like a patch. So I have to find proper event binding which CKeditor provides.

Comment: @Maharshi check my answer.

Comment: @Maharshi check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will work. For CKeditor you can replace `editor.on('dblclick', function (evt) {` line with this line `editor.on('doubleclick', function (evt) {`

[Check this link.](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-doubleclick)

```
    function singleClick(e) {
       console.log('single click');
   }

   function doubleClick(e) {
       console.log('double click');
   }

   editor.on('dblclick', function (evt) {
        $(this).data('double', 2);
        doubleClick.call(this, evt);
        //Some ajax calls
    }, null, null, 999 );
    editor.on('click', function (evt) {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var dblclick = parseInt($(that).data('double'), 10);
            if (dblclick > 0) {
                $(that).data('double', dblclick-1);
            } else {
                singleClick.call(that, evt);
            }
        }, 300);
        //Some ajax calls
    }, null, null);
```