# clearTimeout is not working

Tags: javascript

SetTimeout is not working for the follwing code:

```
   $("#clkDblClk").click(function(){           
       var clickTimer=setTimeout(function(){
            //Some code to execute
          },1000); 
        $(this).data("clickTimer",clickTimer);
     });
     $("#clkDblClk").dblclick(function(){
       var clickTimer=$(this).data("clickTimer");
       clearTimeout(clickTimer);
       //Some ajaxRequest
     });
```

The element is registered for both click and double click events.To cancel out click event on doubleclick, setTimeout function is registered.I get the Ineger timer id in double click method, but clearTimeout is not cancelling out the function to execute. I'm not getting the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067464/need-to-cancel-click-mouseup-events-when-double-click-event-detected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish between a click and a double-click, so every double-click **also** triggers two separate click events. Each of *those* click events is *also* starting the `setTimeout`, but it overwrites the `.data('clickTimer')` value.

---

Here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Az6zY/

---

One solution is to debounce the `click` event. Really simple implementation:

```
var DATA_KEY = 'clickTimer';

$('#clkDblClk').click(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.data(DATA_KEY)) return;

    var clickTimer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        // do other stuff

        $this.removeData(DATA_KEY);
    }, 1000);

    $this.data(DATA_KEY, clickTimer);
})
.dblclick(function()
{
    var $this = $(this);

    var clickTimer = $this.data(DATA_KEY);
    clearTimeout(clickTimer);

    $this.removeData(DATA_KEY);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/B5MSw/