# Prevent Opera's select text/double left click menu with Dojo

Tags: javascript, select, dojo, opera, double-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable doubleclick event for an element in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203286/disable-doubleclick-event-for-an-element-in-opera)

I've got problem with Opera browser. It's only one that does show up context menu on double left click/selection. I have page with div's which are empty (background images). They have hooked click and contextmenu events and click is working fine when you click *slow*. If you click twice faster text get's selected. What I observed is that probably main reason for this is using *inline-block*, just because of treating whole as one line. Here is example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: 1"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <div id="test" style="height: 38px; width: 38px; background: red;">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <div id="test" style="height: 38px; width: 38px; background: red;">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on","dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, on) {
    on(dom.byId('test'), 'click', function() { /* do something here */ return false; });
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to prevent it, leaving *inline-block*? I'm especially interested in solution with Dojo, if possible.

Comment: I've switched div's to float: left for now, but if anyone would have any way to prevent it I'll be happy to accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has little to do with your code and everything with Opera's default settings.

Here is an article on how to [disable contextmenu on double-click](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/06/opera-disable-context-menu-on-double.html). Obviously this does not solve your problem since it is a setting on the client side you have no control over.