# Submit only once on double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to cancel click/mouseup events when double-click event detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067464/need-to-cancel-click-mouseup-events-when-double-click-event-detected)
>   [Preventing double-click of Submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944254/preventing-double-click-of-submit-button)

I have following function

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
                $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          ....make ajax request
              $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");

}
```

Problem is that I want to handle 1st click of a double click . Or a single click . Because when user double clicks it does run the function twice . If I use .one() it will handle only single clicks . But I also want to handle double clicks but only handle it once . Whats solution ?

Comment: Handling both single- and double-clicks in web applications is almost impossible and, for usability reasons, a terrible idea.

Comment: Also you should use ".prop()" to set/unset the "disabled" property: `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.prop("disabled", false)`.

Comment: After the First Click i Would disable the Button.

Comment: @Pointy. Should be an answer... :)

Comment: Or maybe better: [Preventing double-click of Submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944254/preventing-double-click-of-submit-button) -- please use the search.

Comment: Your `disabled` solution should work, as long as you enable it *inside the AJAX callback*. Can't tell what you're actually doing.

Comment: It's tempting to down vote all these "flag" solutions. What OP is already doing is superior, but is being done incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`dblclick()`

instead of `click()`

Read more about **[`.dblclick()`](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)**

Your code should look like

```
$("#btnSubmit").dblclick(function(){
   $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

You can use a flag

```
var alreadyClicked = false;
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
   if(alreadyClicked) {
      alreadyClicked = false;
      return false;
   } else {
     alreadyClicked = true;
     $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
   }
});
```

Comment: Pure JS docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.ondblclick

Comment: This won't handle single clicks.

Comment: 2nd code block wont differentiate between a double click vs subsequent single clicks . So once a button is clicked user wont be able to submit it with change of data .

Answer (score 1):

Set a sentinel variable to prevents further clicks from being acted upon until the ajax request completes:

```
var clicked = false;
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    if (clicked) {
        return;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
    }
    $.ajax({
      success: function() {
          clicked = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would stop the double click my checking for a variable when the button is pressed.

What happens is that the click variable works as a check to see if the function is currently running.

```
var click = false;
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

  if (click == false) {
    click = true;

    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    //make ajax request

    $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");

    click = false;
  }
}
```