# javascript differentiate between click and double click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a simple program like:

```
<div onclick="handleClick(event)" ondblclick="handleDoubleClick(event)">
  Hellooww world
</div>
<script>
    var a = false
    function handleClick(e) {
    if(a) {
        a = false
            console.log("Hellooww", a)
    }else{
        a = true
      console.log("Hellooww", a)
    }
    }

  function handleDoubleClick(e) {
    console.log("world")
  }
</script>
```

Here on single click it sets the value of a to true of false.. But when its double click it perfomrs both single click and double click

How can I check only for single click and double click

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event

Comment: This answer is interesting (and relevant): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1068302/218196 .

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497073/how-to-differentiate-single-click-event-and-double-click-event) provides details on why the behavior is happening, but here is the solution to your specific use case. The one possible approach is to use `timeout` and some wait time. The problem is that there is no standard interval to wait. Although you could use the `300 ms` timing that [a mobile browser uses](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/) to distinguish between `tap` and `double tap` event:

```
var a = false;
var timeout;
function handleClick(e) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if (a) {
            a = false
            console.log("Hellooww", a)
        } else {
            a = true
            console.log("Hellooww", a)
        }
    }, 300);
}

function handleDoubleClick(e) {
    if (timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    console.log("world")
}
```

But generally, don't register click and dblclick events on the same element: it's impossible to distinguish correctly single-click events from click events that lead to a dblclick event.

Comment: How did you arrive at the 300ms?

Comment: @FelixKling, that's a valid question :). I remember reading somewhere that it's the time a browser waits to distinguish a double click or another click event. Is this not true?

Comment: I don't know, but having a resource to back this up would be great!

Comment: @FelixKling, actually, it seems that this interval of `300` ms [is pertaining](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/) to `tap` and `double tap` event, not sure if it applies to `click` and `dblclick`. I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: @Maximus it seems good approach but here when I double click it will log world in the console also it will execute `handleClick` at the end.. I dont want to execute `handleClick` when I do  double click

Comment: @aryan, yeah, this is tricky, it's because `click` is triggered two times, one before `dbclick` and one after. I thought the `click` after `dblclick` shouldn't be triggered. I don't know how to handle this situation